# Use the Well ordering principle to prove

Tags: well-orders

Is there a process that is capable of generating an infinitely long sequence of natural numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ such that for all $n \ge 1, a_n \ge a_{n+1}$?

I know i have to use the well ordering principle to prove this. You assume that there a largest an and prove a contradiction. But isn't WOP used to show that there is a smallest element in a non empty set? How would i start this?

Comment: What does "an+1" mean in this context?

Comment: Sorry i am trying to write the subscript a <sub> n+1

Comment: One statement of the well ordering principle is that there is no infinite descending chain.  That rules out exactly what you are asking about.  You are asked to derive that from whatever version of the well ordering principle you are given.  What is it?

Comment: It is asking if there is a process so i guess i can prove that there isn't such process

Comment: You can actually use the pigeonhole principle as an alternative proof.  There are only finitely many natural numbers less than $a_1$.

Comment: @bow123 if you are satisfied with your answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a proof where you should just use what you know - you recognize that the well-ordering principle tells you something about a least element, so let's investigate that! There's nothing special about a largest element* (especially since $a_0 \geq a_1 \geq a_2 \ldots$ implies that $a_0$ is the largest... which wasn't very interesting).

So, let's suppose we have a sequence $a_0\geq a_1\geq a_2 \geq \ldots$. To apply the well-ordering principle, we need to come up with a non-empty set - and the set $\{a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$ is the only thing in sight, so let's use the well-ordering theorem on that! This means that there is some $a_n$ such that $a_n \leq a_m$ for all $m$ - and now we're basically done! Look at any $m\geq n$. We know (or can prove by induction) that since $a_n \geq a_m$ since the sequence is non-increasing. However, we just used this magic principle to choose $n$ so that $a_n \leq a_m$. That means that $a_n=a_m$! In particular, following this line of reasoning gives us the following:

> Given any non-increasing sequence of natural numbers, there is some term $a_n$ after which the sequence is constant.

Which says that, no matter how you start, you'll end with something like $c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,\ldots$ where the term $c$ goes on forever.

---

*Saying there's nothing special about a largest element is *somewhat* of a lie. You can prove the statement I highlighted by induction on $a_0$ - if $a_0=0$, we are done because there are no smaller natural numbers. Then, you can note that this implies that if the sequence *ever* hits $0$, it must be constant - but then if you investigate $a_0=1$, you find that either the sequence eventually hits $0$, or it repeats $1$ forever - and you can twist this into a formal inductive argument. This is not the easiest path, however. You can also do things like suppose that $a_0>a_1>\ldots$ is strictly decreasing and show that it can have at most $1+a_0$ terms, or just look at the finite set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,a_0\}$ and ask how many times each term repeats.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is one such sequence...**

$$5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...$$

the above is an infinitely long sequence of natural numbers such that $a_n \ge a_{n+1}$ for $n \ge 1$. It is sufficient to use this sequence as proof that such a sequence exists. A proof of this kind would be called a "constructive existence proof," and the above sequence would be a "witness" to the statement you are trying to prove.

If you were searching for an infinitely long sequence of natural numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3, ...$ such that $a_n > a_{n+1}$ for $n \ge 1$, then I would say no such sequence exists by the well ordering principle, which states that every nonempty subset of the natural numbers has a least element. In that event, you would be looking for a way to arrange the natural numbers such that they descend forever without ever encountering a least element beyond which there was no lesser number. Of course, the natural numbers have a least element, that is, the number $0$, so any "process" or function that generates a descending sequence of natural numbers will either terminate before it encounters $0$ or encounter $0$ and have to stop. In either case, the sequence is not infinite.